# WooCommerce - How to display unavailable (out of stock, invisible) variations in the variations drop-down on the single product page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

On a website, I need to display out-of-stock variations in the drop-down grayed out and with the additional text "sold out". This was possible through a Woocommerce hook. But I had to disable the Woocommerce checkbox to "hide out-of-stock items from the catalog", because otherwise the out-of-stock variations would be hidden completely from the drop-down.

The problem: Products with out-of-stock variations are still shown in archives (shop page, categories, attribute archives, search results) and this is not desired.
So the only possibility might be to "hide out-of-stock items from the catalog" and still display the out-of-stock variations in the dropdown.

I tried to overwrite the WooCommerce `wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options()` function to modify the select options. The `<options>` there are populated by the `$terms` variable. When I var_dump() this variable right before the `<select>`, I see that all attributes are in place (visible and invisible ones). But they are hidden from the HTML, obviously by AJAX.
How can I make them visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items( $pre_option ) {
    
    // Disable hide option dynamicaly on product page only
    if(is_product()){
        return 'no';
    }

    return $pre_option;
}
add_filter( 'pre_option_woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items', 'woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works great and solved my problem. And I learned about the "pre_option" filter that I never needed before.

Comment: there is a filter `woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items`. couldn't find the `pre_option` one anywhere in a current wc installation

Comment: @honk31 - This is a hook available in the WP core itself `$pre = apply_filters( "pre_option_{$option}", false, $option, $default_value );`